# Using the crosstab() function while appending to the column names & using boolean logic

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I'm using Postgresl 9.2

I need a crosstab table created from this:

`select id, imp from sg_imp_id` (There are A LOT more rows than this)

```
  id   |  imp  |
-------+-------+
  1    |  111  |
  2    |  111  | 
  2    |  121  | 
  2    |  122  |
  3    |  131  |
  4    |  154  |
  ....    ....
```

Like this:

```
    id   | x111 | x121 | x122 | x131 | x154 |
---------+------+------+------+------+------+
    1    |   1  |   0  |  0   |  0   |  0   |
    2    |   1  |   1  |  1   |  0   |  0   |
    3    |   0  |   0  |  0   |  1   |  0   |
    4    |   0  |   0  |  0   |  0   |  1   |
```

With a column for every `imp` row and whenever an `id` has that `imp` number, to place a 1. If it doesn't have that `imp` number 
then a 0 should be in that spot. I have very limited knowledge of the `crosstab()` function. There are currently very many different rows of "x111,x112,x113" values so using the `case` clause won't really be probable.

Comment: So you just want to prefix the column names that `crosstab` produces? Have you look at the `crosstab` source?

Comment: I want to prefix the column names but I don't even know how to get my results as their own column using `crosstab()`

Comment: But you can get `crosstab()` to give you `111`, `121`, ... as column names?

Comment: No, I haven't figured out how to do that @muistooshort

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about crosstab() function, but you can always pivot manually:

```
select
    id,
    max(case when imp = 111 then 1 else 0 end) as x111,
    max(case when imp = 121 then 1 else 0 end) as x121,
    max(case when imp = 122 then 1 else 0 end) as x122,
    max(case when imp = 131 then 1 else 0 end) as x131,
    max(case when imp = 154 then 1 else 0 end) as x154
from Table1
group by id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a6722/2)</kbd>**

Comment: The only problem with using this method is there are more than just the rows I added. There are tons of x122,x123,x124 etc.. There are so many that manually writing them all out is virtually impossible.

Comment: Afaik there's no way to return dynamic number of columns in Postgresql. And, actually, it's not good idea.SQL is designed to have fixed number of columns and dynamic number of rows, it's usually better to pivot on the client side

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it , It is some useful to you

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SQL = ISNULL(@SQL, '') + ',
(
SELECT  
 id 
FROM  stacky.dbo.crosstab t' + Rownum + ' 
WHERE   t' + Rownum + '.id = t.id   AND     t' + Rownum + '.imp = ''' + imp + ''' 
) 
[x' + imp + ']'
FROM ( SELECT  imp, CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY imp)) [RowNum] FROM   stacky.dbo.crosstab  GROUP BY imp) d



SET @SQL = 'SELECT id ' + @SQL + ' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM stacky.dbo.crosstab) t'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Please Change DAtabase name 
 and (id int),(imp varchar(20)) type
Other then use casting

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: It is Sql server Query